# convert R percentage equation to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am trying to convert this function to pandas as I am not familiar with R

```
sum(data_file$finished_race_date >= 0, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(data_file$signup_race_date >= 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I am trying to figure out what percentage of runners finished the race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need divide sum of `True` values in 2 boolean masks comparing by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
100 * data_file.finished_race_date.notnull().sum()/data_file.signup_race_date.notnull().sum()
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_file = pd.DataFrame({'finished_race_date':['2/5/16',np.nan,np.nan],
                          'signup_race_date':[np.nan,'2/5/16','2/5/16']})

print (data_file)
  finished_race_date signup_race_date
0             2/5/16              NaN
1                NaN           2/5/16
2                NaN           2/5/16

print (data_file.finished_race_date.notnull())
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: finished_race_date, dtype: bool

print (data_file.finished_race_date.notnull().sum())
1

finished_race_date = data_file.finished_race_date.notnull().sum()
signup_race_date = data_file.signup_race_date.notnull().sum()

print (100 * finished_race_date / signup_race_date)
50.0
```

Comment: i got this error message back:                                                           numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'div'

Comment: what return `(data_file.finished_race_date >= 0)` ?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cf163a7b4c10> in <module>()
----> 1 print (data_file.finished_race_date >= 0).sum().div((data_file.signup_race_date >= 0).sum())

Comment: What is `print (data_file.finished_race_date)` ?

Comment: NaN
  NaN
  NaN
  2/3/16
  NaN
Name:finished_race_date, dtype: object   **thats the .head()**